# Speechmatics - Getting API key error after I add some configurations

Tags: artificial-intelligence, openai-api, whisper

My code runs for the simple configuration below:

```
from speechmatics.models import ConnectionSettings
from speechmatics.batch_client import BatchClient
from httpx import HTTPStatusError 

AUTH_TOKEN = "YOUR_API_KEY"
PATH_TO_FILE = "example.wav"
LANGUAGE = "en"

settings = ConnectionSettings(
    url="https://asr.api.speechmatics.com/v2",
    auth_token=AUTH_TOKEN,
)

# Define transcription parameters
conf = {
    "type": "transcription",
    "transcription_config": { 
        "language": LANGUAGE,
        # Find out more about entity detection here:
        # https://docs.speechmatics.com/features/entities#enable-entity-metadata
        "enable_entities": True,
    },
}

# Open the client using a context manager
with BatchClient(settings) as client:
    try:
        job_id = client.submit_job(
            audio=PATH_TO_FILE,
            transcription_config=conf,
        )
        print(f"job {job_id} submitted successfully, waiting for transcript")

        # Note that in production, you should set up notifications instead of polling. 
        # Notifications are described here: https://docs.speechmatics.com/features-other/notifications
        transcript = client.wait_for_completion(job_id, transcription_format="txt")
        # To see the full output, try setting transcription_format="json-v2".
        print(transcript)
    except HTTPStatusError:
        print("Invalid API key - Check your AUTH_TOKEN at the top of the code!")
```

However, the moment I add a new configuration setting like "diarization": "speaker" I get the HTTPStatusError running the print statement: Invalid API key - Check your AUTH_TOKEN at the top of the code!

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Config seems fine so it might be incorrect error message. Try printing more details from `HTTPStatusError` as `response.status_code` and `response.content`.

Comment: Got a 403 error. Could it be that the additional config needs an upgrade?